# How to access attribute

Tags: ruby

I want to put the name of the enemies (toto and titi). How can I do that ?

My simplified code :

```
class Gamer
  attr_accessor :name, ...
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    ...
  end
  ...
end

class Enemy < Gamer
  ...
end

class Map
  attr_accessor :enemies
  ...
end    
##############
map = Map.new
map.enemies = [
  Enemy.new("toto"),
  Enemy.new("titi")
]

puts "#{map.enemies}"
```

I'm a beginner in Ruby

return :

```
[#<Gamer:0x000002e29da0 @name="toto">, #<Gamer:0x000002e29d50 @name="titi">]
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then:

```
map.enemies.each do |enemy|
  puts enemy.name
end
```

Return an array of names

```
puts map.enemies.map(&:name)
```

Comment: you can directly `puts` array too. Here: `puts map.enemies.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method `to_s` in `Enemy`. This method is used when you `puts` an object:

```
class Enemy
  ...
  def to_s
    @name
  end
end

enemy = Enemy.new("foo")

puts enemy
#=> foo
```

To print the names of an `Array` of objects, you can then use `join` on the `Array`:

```
map = Map.new

map.enemies = [Enemy.new("foo"), Enemy.new("bar")]

puts map.enemies.join(", ")
#=> foo, bar
```

This has the benefit that the `Enemy` object now is responsible for knowing how it should be printed, rather than this behaviour being spread across the code that uses `Enemy`.

Comment: The _proper_ way would be to use special printer objects. But that's probably way too high OOP for this program :)

Comment: I am tempted to say the *Java* way, but yes. :-P